# verilog multiplication results is zero?

Tags: verilog

i'm trying to multiply two 32 bit signed fractional number (1 sign bit, 8 integer bit, 23 fraction bit)

the first one is

32'b0_00000001_00000000000000000000000 // 1.00

the 2nd one is

32'b0_00000100_00000000000000000000000 // 4.00

when i do like this for example

output signed[31:0] a;

assign a = 32'b0_00000001_00000000000000000000000 * 32'b0_00000100_00000000000000000000000;

the results is zero? why it isn't 4?

kindly please help me in which part i am mistaken and what should i do. thank you very much

regards

Isaac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to assign a 64 bit value to a 32 bit wire, and Verilog will truncate the value, keeping only the lower 32 bits of the result, which is zero.

To have a proper result, you can do as this:

```
module mult;
  reg [31:0] a = 32'b0_00000001_00000000000000000000000;  // 1.0
  reg [31:0] b = 32'b0_00000100_00000000000000000000000;  // 4.0

  reg [63:0] t;
  reg [31:0] c;

  initial begin
    t = a * b;
    c = t[54:23];

    $display ("%b",c);
    $finish;
  end  
endmodule
```